# Solr Query non UTF-8 Characters

Tags: java, tomcat, encoding, utf-8, solr

I have a Solr cluster with Name field defined as:

```
<field name="Name" type="token" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="false"/>

<fieldType name="token" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="1">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I have data stored in this field as:

```
[[\"ЕЅelimir\", \"FГ¤rber\", \"\", \"\"]]
[[\"Jexper\", \"Testäverde\", \"\", \"\"]]
```

When I query for this feild from Solr Admin console, I am able to get the document. I have a java spring tomcat application on top of Solr, which builds the Solr query and runs it against solr. When I try to search through the Java application, I dont get the matching documents in return.

My java application encodes the query URL in UTF-8.
My java tomcat server.xml has URIEncoding="UTF-8".

Nothing seems to help. Any ideas to fix this would be helpful.

Query in Solr logs when queried from,

```
Admin console    : [[\"??elimir\",+\"F??rber\",+\"\",+\"\"]] --> Gives match
Java application : [[\"ESelimir\",+\"F????rber\",+\"\",+\"\"]] --> Gives no match
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the UTF-8 encoding to the request headers when you make the call to Solr from the Java appication.